# How to create Silent Opus Audio Files

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, opus

I need silent Opus audio files range of 1 second to 60 minutes.

I found this example for wav files:

> 60 seconds of silent audio in WAV:
>
> ffmpeg -ar 48000 -t 60 -f s16le -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 2 -i /dev/zero
>   -acodec copy output.wav
>
> 60 seconds of silent audio in MP3:
>
> ffmpeg -ar 48000 -t 60 -f s16le -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 2 -i /dev/zero
>   -acodec libmp3lame -aq 4 output.mp3

How can I do it for opus with using ffmpeg or similar tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a recent build of ffmpeg, run

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc -ac 2 -ar 48000 -t 30 -c:a libopus file.opus
```

You can add `-vbr 0 -b:a 128k` for a CBR encode.

Comment: Minimal command: `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc -t $n file.opus` where `$n` is the length in seconds.